# json-server - Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension

Tags: angularjs, json-server

I am running an express server to serve my angularJS app on port 8000. I'm using an `$http.get` inside one of my services to hit an API.
I'm using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to host the API on 3000. When I enter the URL in the browser, I get the JSON served. But when I open the app, the following error is shown in devtools:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/techData. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

this is the angularjs service:

```
techApp.factory('techData', function ($http) {
  let data;
  $http.get('localhost:3000/techData')
    .then((response) => {
      data = response.data;
    });

    return {
      techData: data
    };
});
```

I saw [this issue](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/124) and learnt that json-server allows cross origin requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, in case anyone is here, I had not used the URL with `http`. Changing the argument given to `$http.get` as follows solved the problem:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/techData')
```